# How do I properly install GFCI outlets with existing 12/3 wire in parallel and on a switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, gfci, receptacle

I am trying to help my inlaws with a problem in their living room.  Two of their outlets stopped working and I don't really know why.  The outlets were wired to a switch in the hallway, which controlled the top outlet, and the bottom outlet was always powered.  They were also the middle outlets in a series of 6. I purchased 2 Leviton brand slim GFCI outlets.  When unhooking the existing outlets, I noticed that both red wires were attached to the top "brass" connector, and both black wires were attached to the bottom "brass" connector, while the white wires were attached to the silver connectors.  I have tried every combination of wires I can think of and cannot get it to work.

Any advice?

Comment: As Tester said, this cannot be done with a GFI receptacle. Why are you using a GFI to begin with?

Answer (score 4):

You can't do what you want with GFCI receptacles.  You'll have to buy a couple regular duplex receptacles, and write them exactly as the old ones were wired.  And don't forget to break off the tab between the terminals, on the "hot" side of the receptacles.